# How to add string to date function - Progress 4gl

Tags: date, progress-4gl, openedge

I am newbie in Progress and I've Trouble in date function Progress 4gl.

Example I have string value = '2016 '.

How do I put that value into a date in Progress?

Example:

```
def var xx as char.
def var xq as date.

ASSIGN 
  xx = '2016'
  xq = DATE(01/01/xx).
```

Answer (score 4):

While it is possible to write

```
ASSIGN 
  xx = '2016':U
  xq = DATE('01/01/':U + xx)
.
```

I would prefer

```
ASSIGN 
  xx = '2016':U
  xq = DATE(1,1,integer(xx))
.
```

(The first example is dependent on the current date format. If you look up the DATE function in the OpenEdge Help you can see that DATE ( month, day, year ) is valid, too.)

Comment: Add error handling! You always need to check input and/or output when typecasting. A simple added NO-ERROR and validity check (xq <>?) could do it in this case.